# Can I enable Azure Functions when a Traffic Manager failover event occurs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-traffic-manager

I have primary and secondary versions of a function app deployed to two different regions for high availability. I have a Traffic Manager profile that sits in front of these apps to monitor endpoint health and direct traffic appropriately.

Two of the functions in the app use non-HTTP triggers, specifically `QueueTrigger` and `TimerTrigger`. The problem is that these functions are executing in the secondary region, even when the Traffic Manager is directing all requests to the primary region.

I would like to have both of these functions disabled in secondary, to be enabled only when the Traffic Manager performs a failover upon detecting a problem with primary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since you're not using HTTP Trigger. Also, even if you failover to the secondary region, it would not have the messages / from the primary region, unless you're copying to both storage accounts. The best you can do (IMHO) is to define the data redundancy as Geo-zone-redundant storage and let Azure handle this for you.